# Finding Marginal density from Joint CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

$F(x,y) =  1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}+e^{-x-y}, (x,y) >= 0 $ and $0$ otherwise.

I found the joint pdf by differentiating by x and y to get $f(x,y) = e^{-x-y}$

However, when I find the marginal distributions of x and y they are both just 1. Is this valid? Or did I do something wrong here?

Comment: How do you find each marginal distribution?

Comment: $f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{\inf} e^{-x-y} dy$ and $f_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{\inf} e^{-x-y} dx$

Comment: $=exp(-x)$ so $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Comment: @YJT Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve the problem is just to observe that

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=e^{-x-y}\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(y)$$

can be factorized in

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(x)\times e^{-y}\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(y)=f_X(x)\times f_Y(y)$$

Thus the two marginals are iid Exp(1)